# Trigger properties not working in WPF button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create minimize, maximize and close buttons for my form in WPF. I can create the buttons fine but when I am hovering or clicking the buttons, they do not change color, even though the XAML is set for them to do so. Can someone take a look and see what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="HighlightColor">#FF3F3F41</Color>
    <Color x:Key="BlueColor">#FF007ACC</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ForegroundColor">#FFF4F4F5</Color>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource HighlightColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource BlueColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource ForegroundColor}"/>

    <Style x:Key="WindowButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ForegroundColorBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                      RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightColorBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BlueColorBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter" Property="Opacity" Value=".5" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Here is the code for my buttons, none of them work.:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" Grid.Row="0">
            <Button Command="{Binding Source={x:Static shell:SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}}" ToolTip="minimize" Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Grid Width="30" Height="25" RenderTransform="1,0,0,1,0,1">
                        <Path Data="M0,6 L8,6 Z" Width="8" Height="7" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                        Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" StrokeThickness="2"  />
                    </Grid>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
            <Grid Margin="1,0,1,0">
                <Button x:Name="Restore" Command="{Binding Source={x:Static shell:SystemCommands.RestoreWindowCommand}}" ToolTip="restore" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Grid Width="30" Height="25" UseLayoutRounding="True" RenderTransform="1,0,0,1,.5,.5">
                            <Path Data="M2,0 L8,0 L8,6 M0,3 L6,3 M0,2 L6,2 L6,8 L0,8 Z" Width="8" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                            Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" StrokeThickness="1"  />
                        </Grid>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="Maximize" Command="{Binding Source={x:Static shell:SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand}}" ToolTip="maximize" Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Grid Width="31" Height="25">
                            <Path Data="M0,1 L9,1 L9,8 L0,8 Z" Width="9" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                            Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" StrokeThickness="2"  />
                        </Grid>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
            <Button Command="{Binding Source={x:Static shell:SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}}" ToolTip="close"  Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Grid Width="30" Height="25" RenderTransform="1,0,0,1,0,1">
                        <Path Data="M0,0 L8,7 M8,0 L0,7 Z" Width="8" Height="7" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                        Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" StrokeThickness="1.5"  />
                    </Grid>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Please take out the command and check once i have checked out its working fine with out command.I am not familiar with Prism and i don't know what is shell and all.I think you need to do something w.r.t command. Let me know how is it works now.

Comment: @Dineshreddybandi StaticShell is a part of the WPF shell integration library. When I remove the command from the buttons the triggers do in fact work. Thank you very much for suggesting that. I believe it must of happened due to an issue with the fact I didnt add the c# code behind for the commands yet. I didnt think it mattered for the triggers though, I guess it does. Some of the differences between WinForms and WPF throw me off. There is alot I need to get used to. Your suggestion worked though, thank you. If you want to post it as an answer you can, and I will select it.

Comment: @user1632018 See if the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000830/control-template-visibility-triggers works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take out the command and check once i have checked out its working fine with out command.I am not familiar with Prism and i don't know what is shell and all.I think you need to do something w.r.t command. Let me know how is it works now

Answer (score 1):

We need to define a CommandBindings which associates the command to its handler.  Below is the xaml and codebehind. Try and let me know if it helps you.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CommandBinding cmdBinding = new CommandBinding (Microsoft.Windows.Shell.SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand,
                CloseCommandHandler);
            this.CommandBindings.Add(cmdBinding);
        }

        private void CloseCommandHandler(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Parameter != null)
            {
                (e.Parameter as Window).Close();
            }
        }
    }

<Button x:Name="btn3" Command="shell:SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myWindow}" ToolTip="close"  Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}">
            <Button.Content>
                <Grid Width="30" Height="25" RenderTransform="1,0,0,1,0,1">
                    <Path Data="M0,0 L8,7 M8,0 L0,7 Z" Width="8" Height="7" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                        Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" StrokeThickness="1.5"  />
                </Grid>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
```

Note: myWindow in the Xaml command parameter is the name of the window.